# Models where $\Bbb R$ is not a countable union of countable sets and $\omega_1$ is singular

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

We have the following implication:

> Any countable union of countable sets is countable $\rightarrow$ $\omega_1$ is regular $\rightarrow$ $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is not a countable union of countable sets.

According to the [Choiceless Grapher](https://cgraph.inters.co/selection-diagram?31=on&34=on&38=on), these implications are not reversible. But I can't seem to locate the references. Can someone point me to where these non-reversibility results are located? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first thing, any symmetric extension built with either Cohen reals, or without adding new reals (or generally without collapsing $\omega_1$) will have $\omega_1$ regular. As such it's easy to arrange a model where the reverse implication of the first arrow fails. So, for example, the second Cohen model where there is a countable union of pairs without a choice function. You can also arrange this in the level of the reals by adding a countable sequence of countable sets of reals and not having a uniform enumeration of all these new sets.

The second one is trickier, but here are two ways:

1. The Truss' model is a model where $\omega_1$ is regular, but $\Bbb R$ is not the countable union of countable sets. The idea is to mimic the Solovay model, but to start with a singular cardinal and not necessarily an inaccessible cardinal.

   > *Truss, John*, [**Models of set theory containing many perfect sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(74)90015-1), Ann. Math. Logic 7, 197-219 (1974). [ZBL0302.02024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0302.02024).
2. Use the Feferman–Levy model where we collapse $\aleph_\omega$ and also add $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ Cohen reals (before or after, it doesn't matter since it's a well-ordered forcing in any model of $\sf ZF$ it will not destroy "families without a choice function"). Or generally first blow the continuum above $\aleph_\omega$ to have a regular cardinality (just to simplify things) and then collapse $\aleph_\omega$ to be $\omega_1$.

Comment: Thanks! In the Truss model, $\omega_1$ is singular, right?

Comment: Of course. It was singular in the ground model.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $38$ does not imply $34$ can be found in *Zermelo's Axiom of Choice* by G.H. Moore ($1982$) page $324$. I found this by looking in the book CGraph is based off of. I couldn't find anything about whether or not $34$ implies $31$. It seems this could be an open problem. At the very least I don't think the book mentions it.